# Assistance needed to solve the issue with Maven shaded plugin issue whenever sonarqube dependencies are added

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

If any one can help I am facing a strange issue, when ever I add the command for sonarqube analysis along with some edits to to POM files

```
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>0.8.2</version>
```

as analysis through plugin is not allowed in our organization

```
clean install -U -Dbuild.version=${BUILD_NUMBER} clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=VYC0:itfc-aperture-group -Dsonar.projectName=itfc-aperture-group -Dsonar.login=abcd -Dsonar.password=${mypassword} -Dsonar.sources=/app/jenkins/workspace/workspace/test-group -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqubep12.com:9000
```

so we have to add this in the option maven goals as below I get the error as this

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) on project itfc-aperture-uber: Error creating shaded jar:
```

but when I just run with **clean install -U** there is no error why so? Please guide me

Snippet from the POM which is failing when the sonarqube code is added in goal but will run fine when there is no sonar scanning request.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```